# how to make infinite animation pause at the end then go back css

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to build a slide-in content that runs infinite times every time a new word appears
the problem is when I set the  animation-iteration-count to infinite it becomes so hard to read because it doesn't pause
I want it to pause for 2s then go back and play
do I need JavaScriptfor it??

Comment: Can you add your current code so we can imagine the situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You need to provide the code you have tried for other SO contributors to have a chance of helping you. This link provides guidelines on how to create a Minimal Reproducible Example in your post >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example